# Accumulo, modifying previous keys using the TransformingIterator

Tags: java, accumulo

I am currently just started writing my very own java client for accumulo.
I am able to write and read records, I now want to modify some existing keys using the `TransformingIterator` class (https://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/iterators/user/TransformingIterator.html#TransformingIterator())

Since it was a while since I coded in java last time, I don't really understand how to use this class and I'm not able to find any good examples or explanations on this.

Does someone know how to use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd caution you against trying to use this class on your own. It has a lot of caveats that make it tricky to get correct (not to mention Iterators being tricky already on their own).

Unless you have a very large amount of data (terabytes), it is likely going to be easier to transform your data using some batch-processing tool (e.g. MapReduce) instead of trying to use the TransformingIterator.